# Keras Not so Dense Layer

Tags: keras, embedding

Previous layer is embedding size (V clasess,K -outputdim) - I want to introduce a weights matrix size K x T. The weights will be trainable (as will the embeddings).They generate a VxT matrix  will be used downstream.
1) How might I go about this?
2) Will this mess with the gradients?

It's basically vector x Matrix .
Example- embedding vocab = 10, dim K =4. so for a particular member of vocabulary, my embedding weights is a vector size (1,4) (think row vector).

For each row vector I want to multiply a weight matrix size 4x10, yielding a 1 x 10 vector (or layer) . The weight matrix is common to all members of the vocabulary.

This 1 x 10 vector will be input for the next layer.

Comment: I don't see the difference with a Dense layer (without bias), you have to be extremely clear about what you want to do, and what is the (programming) problem.

Comment: More clarification above

Comment: Matias, I see what you mean! Thanks. Post it as answer please. Now Isee that the dense weights are common to all inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a Dense layer, just without a bias. A Dense layer internally has a matrix that is common for all inputs, it does not vary with the input.

So this can be implemented as:

```
x = Dense(10, use_bias=False)(some_input_tensor)
```

No activation function is needed since you just want the matrix multiplication.